# Doxygen: \code tag kills indentation

Tags: doxygen

In doxygen I write:

```
/*! Sample:

\code{.cpp}
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "no way!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        foobar(argv[1]);
    }
}
\endcode
*/
```

Now doxygen will generate a perfectly syntax-highlighted code sample for my documentation, but unfortunately it also kills the indentation:

Sample:

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if (argc < 2)
{
cout << "no way!" << endl;
}
else
{
foobar(argv[1]);
}
}
```

What can I do to make doxygen respect my indentation. I know there is \verbatim, but it does not highlight the syntax.

---

EDIT:
Here's the doxygen configuration, perhaps there's something wrong in there:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = demo
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ../../../../../Desktop/dox
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = YES
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = NO
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = NO
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = C:\Users\foobar\Desktop\dox\demo.log

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = ../demo/src/export
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = header.html
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://www.mathjax.org/mathjax
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4wide
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
HAVE_DOT               = NO
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = FreeSans
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = \\somewhere\over\the\rainbow
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 1000
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = YES
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES

DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Doxygen 1.8.1.1 or older the indentation will be respected.
Doxygen Release 1.8.1.2 removes leading indentation shared by the @code lines. Check the [Change log released on 12-07-2012.](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html#1.8.1.2)

Comment: This misfeature is fixed in version 1.8.7 (or maybe earlier), however,  Markdown-style code blocks still do not preserve indentation. `@code ... @endcode` works fine, but `~~~~~ ... ~~~~~` does not.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and it turned out due to the use of a custom `HTML_STYLESHEET`: our CSS file defined its own styles for `div.fragment` used by Doxygen to wrap code snippets which didn't include `white-space: pre`. Adding it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Update your doxygen html (.css) stylesheet to the latest version.  That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using doxygen 1.8.1 I get a syntax highlighted code block with indentation respected with the example in the question. Which version of doxygen are you using? Perhaps this is just a case of upgrading your version of doxygen. If this is not the solution you will have to provide a bit more context, i.e. is the example documentation you give in your source code in a .txt or .markdown file?

I did have to change your opening comment character from `\` to `/`, I presume this is just a typo. Also, if your file contains C++ source then the `{.cpp}` can be left out of `\code{.cpp}` (i.e. `\code` by itself is fine).

Comment: I also use doxygen 1.8.1. There's two differences between the sample here and the real thing: 1. I start every line of the comment with another asterisk (*) that is aligned to the one in the first line. This does not cause the problem, because I already tried without. 2. My real code is just a little more verbose and part of a class description. And I just used the sample code posted above, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I tried putting your example comments as the documentation of a class method and still got an indented code block. I can't see anything in your configuration file which would cause your problem. (although there is a lot to go through, perhaps you could just include the fields which differ from the default configuration file). Can you provide somemore context - i.e. a small code example which reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when documenting the same code with the same Doxygen 1.8.11 on another (significantly older) computer. All generated output was re-created, including the CSS.

The indentation was visible in the HTML source but the system-default browser refused to show it properly, and a corresponding CHM file behaved likewise (not surprising as the Microsoft's CHM viewer uses the same browser).

Well, it was the browser which is obviously too old for this. Even Firefox 14, which is also quite old, shows the generated HTML with indentation.