# how to prevent doxygen from removing indentation from tcl

Tags: tcl, doxygen

I am producing documentation for my tcl packages. I did set INLINE_SOURCES, however, the white spaces are all removed from the source code when displayed. Is there a way to keep indentation?

Comment: add code example that you tried

Comment: Not a duplicate, but probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190838/doxygen-code-tag-kills-indentation.

Comment: Please state the *exact* version of doxygen that you're using.